# Итеративно вычислить сумму по формуле

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float N, s, a_i;
    int g;
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    g = 1;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= N; counter++)
        {
        if (g % 2 = 0)
        {
            a_i = counter * 3;
        }
        else
        {
            a_i = counter * (counter - 2);
        }
        s += pow((ceil(a_i - g)));
        }
        g+=1
    printf("%f", s);
}
```

В чем ошибка? [image: Задание]

Comment: Впредь давайте вопросам названия, показывающие, о чём **конкретно** идёт речь, а в теле вопроса указывайте, с чего Вы взяли, что у Вас ошибка, а именно: что Вы хотели получить и что получаете сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Да проще написать заново, чем исправлять...

```
long long S(unsigned int N)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        long long a = i*((i%2==0) ? 3 : i-2)-i;
        sum += a*a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Допускаю замену `long long` на `double`, но смысла не вижу :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `=` это присвоение, а `==` это сравнение поэтому место `if (g % 2 = 0)` надо писать `if (g % 2 == 0)`
2. функция `pow` принимает два аргумента - число, степень, а вы передаёт ей одно число. чтобы возвести в квадрат надо писать так `pow(ceil(a_i - g), 2)`
3. `g += 1` вы забыли `;`, и его можно записать как `g++;`
4. `N` у вас равен `0` поэтому цикл сразу заканчивается

Comment: `N` и `s` локальные переменные, а значит нулём не инициализируются.